# Trying to install redmine with nginx and passenger

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, passenger, redmine

I try to install redmine in an Ubuntu 12.04 server with nginx and passenger running in port 3001.
I followed [this tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgpB1.png)

but  I get the following error:

[image]

Bundler is there and when I run **gem list bundler** I get:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.7.10, 1.7.9, 1.7.6, 1.0.21)

Can anybody help me to handle this error with bundler?

Comment: I think you have troubles with installing rvm. According to script (`...bash -s stable --ruby=2.0.0`) you should have active 2.0.0 Ruby but I see 1.8.7 in your stack. Try to close/open terminal to activate RVM (`ruby -v` should return smth like `2.0.0-p123` and not `1.8.7`)

Comment: @gotva OP has no trace of RVM in his traces, why do you assume he uses this (which he does not)? Also, Ruby 2.0 is not required by Redmine (although it is certainly recommended to use something newer than 1.8.7)

Comment: About Ruby 2.0 - maybe you are right. About RVM - @Konstantinos mentioned that he follow instruction above and this instruction suggests to install RVM. PS the first edition of question had link to [tutorial](http://redminecrm.com/boards/4/topics/448-installing-redmine-2-5-passenger-nginx-rvm-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-and-14-04-lts)

Comment: Guys I solved the problem, I removed the rbenv and I installed rvm. Then I added in nginx virtual host tha ruby path, in my case:  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/wrappers/ruby; @gotva you are right about version, 1.8.7 was too old for redmine